# How do I arrange content in thead

Tags: html, html-table

I wan to arrange columns in my thead to look like the below image
 [image]

This my code

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">SUBJECT</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">CA<br> T1 T2 T3</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">CA TOTAL (40)</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">SIGN</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

But it displays like this, how can I split the 'CA' column

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need take 2 rows for thead for display.
Here is the complete code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan='2'>SUBJECT</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">CA</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"  rowspan='2'>CA TOTAL (40)</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"  rowspan='2'>SIGN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="text-align: center;">T1</td>
     <td style="text-align: center;">T2</td>
     <td style="text-align: center;">T3</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't split a cell into more cells, you can only merge existing cells together. That said, if you want to have five columns you need to create five columns, and rather than using a `<br>` to force content to a new line in one cell, and then fake separate cells, use two rows of cells. This, of course, requires the appropriate use of the `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes, such as the following:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-width: 4em;
  min-height: 2em;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}
th {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- rowspan="2" forces the following <th> element
           to span two rows in its containing element: -->
      <th rowspan="2">SUBJECT</th>
      <th colspan="3">CA</th>
      <!-- as it does here also: -->
      <th rowspan="2">CA TOTAL (40)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- this <tr> contains only three <th> elements,
           unlike the previous <tr> which contains five,
           because two <th> elements of the previous row
           will occupy space in this <tr> also -->
      <th>T1</th>
      <th>T2</th>
      <th>T3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>English Language</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mathematics</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bkf1gs4w/).

Incidentally, where possible try to style your content via the use of stylesheets; this makes it far easier to update your style and presentation in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan='2'>SUBJECT</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">CA</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"  rowspan='2'>CA TOTAL (40)</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"  rowspan='2'>SIGN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="text-align: center;">T1</td>
     <td style="text-align: center;">T2</td>
     <td style="text-align: center;">T3</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use rowspan and 2 trs

```css
th { vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">SUBJECT</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">CA</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">CA TOTAL (40)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>T1</th>
          <th>T2</th>
          <th>T3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. Working perfectly:

```
<style>
table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
<table>
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" >SUBJECT</th>
            <th colspan="3">CA</th>
            <th rowspan="2">CA TOTAL (40)</th>
            <th rowspan="2">SIGN</th>
        </tr>
   <tr>
   <th>T1</th>
   <th>T2</th>
   <th>T3</th>
   </tr>

   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>English Language</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mathematics</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

   </tbody> 
    </table>
```